# Google Sheets - Macro to copy values in the next available row

Tags: google-sheets

Total noob here.

I have data that generates in cells A3:F3.
I have recorded a Macro to copy those values to A8.

I have made a button.
I have assignet that button to that Macro.

I can't figure out how to make that button copy the values (just the data) to the next available row.

Please help.

```
    function CopyRow() {
  
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   spreadsheet.getRange('A8').activate();
   spreadsheet.getRange('A3:F3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function CopyRow() {
  
   var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
   var data = sh.getRange('A3:F3').getValues()
   var lastRow = sh.getLastRow()+1
   sh.getRange('A'+lastRow+':F'+lastRow).setValues(data)
  
};
```

Comment: Perfection. Thank you  very much. You helped me a lot!

Live long and prosper!