# Google Sheets - Generate next invoice number, multiple points of sale

Tags: google-sheets, invoice

Situation:
1 company, 3 different points of sale.
I have to make 3 different stacks of invoices.
Invoice numbers are 1/1/1, 1/1/2, 1/1/3, where the first number is incremental, second number is always 1 & third number is the point of sale identifier.

First sheet is data input.
Second is the is invoice generator.
Sheet 3, 4 & 5 are point of sale invoice archive.

I managed to get next invoice number generated depending on the point of sale using the *index* and *left* functions in separate cells but i get the error message along with the result that i actually wanted.

**Is there a simple way to get generated IDs from POS1, POS2, POS3 sheets into a drop-down list data validation without any error?**

Sheet Racun ->Click on the invoice number, choose point of sale (eg. POS1).

Go to sheet POS1 and click save.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RD_rkbtmhC-OKh2dAtc32Qo1p42RdgKaiZsnI8uRKyg/edit?usp=sharing

I am sorry if i didnt explain myself correctly. English is not my mother language.

Comment: by error you mean "Invalid:
Input must be an item on the specified list
" ?

Comment: Would it be possible if you could also share the complete apps script that you're using for replication purposes for the "Save" function?

Comment: Yes player. That error :)

Comment: Irvin https://stackoverflow.com/a/69395548/17042924

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say `Is there a more elegant way to handle this invoice number generator in one string?` do you mean finding an simpler way of getting generated IDs from `POS1`, `POS2`, `POS3` sheets into a drop-down list data validation without any error, correct?

Comment: Hello Irvin. :-). Yes. This is what i would like. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion

You can try adding this onOpen() function below on your Apps Script to automatically get the generated IDs from `POS1`,`POS2`,`POS3` sheets &  build a new data validation drop-down on cell `C11` of the `Racun` sheet.

### Script

```
function CopyRow(){
   var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
   var data = sh.getRange('A3:F3').getDisplayValues();
   var lastRow = sh.getLastRow()+1
   sh.getRange('A'+lastRow+':F'+lastRow).setNumberFormat("@").setValues(data);
}

function onOpen(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Racun").getRange('C11');
  var values = [sh.getSheetByName("POS1").getRange("K2").getValue()+" (POS1)",
                sh.getSheetByName("POS2").getRange("K2").getValue()+" (POS2)",
                sh.getSheetByName("POS3").getRange("K2").getValue()+" (POS3)"];
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(values).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

### Sample Demonstration

After saving & running the script or re-opening of your sheet, you will see the new drop-down:

[image]

> ***NOTE:***
> On your `POS1`,`POS2`,`POS3` sheets, just change the formula on cell `A3` with `=LEFT(Racun!C11, LEN(Racun!C11)-6)` to get the generated IDs, as seen below:

[image]

Comment: If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved & they'll easily see this post on their searches.